# Injectivity in function $f(x)=x\cdot|x|+1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, absolute-value

I want to prove that $f(x) = x\cdot|x|+1$ is injective, and if it is; find the inverse of the function.

$f(a) = f(b) \iff a|a|+1 = b|b|+1 \iff a|a| = b|b|$

$\begin{cases}
-a^2 = b^2 \quad undefined \\
a^2 = b^2\iff
±a = ±b\\
\end{cases}$

It's frustrating to me; I understand the definition behind injectivity; but I suck at proving functions which aren't linear.

So my results were wrong, and I went to try and find the inverse directly instead. Again I divided the absolute value into different cases:

$y = x|x|+1$

If $x<0:\quad -x^2+1=y\iff x=\pm\sqrt{1-y}$

If $x\ge 0:\quad x^2+1=y \iff x=\pm\sqrt{y-1}$

However, according to Wolfram, $f^{-1}(x) = \pm\sqrt{x-1}$. They don't even mention the part when $x\ge0$.

I feel so helpless; the only information I find on the Internet and in my books are for simple equations, such as $y=3x+1$, which doesn't really help me at all.

I need to add that I prefer to learn how to handle it algebraically, as with graphical aid, there's no confusion for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the trick here is that only one of the roots to the equations you give is valid; in particular, you found that, for $x<0$, it holds that
$$-x^2+1=y$$
and therefore that $x=\pm \sqrt{1-y}$, which is correct. However, remember that this is that case *when $x<0$*, and it happens that $\sqrt{1-y}$ is positive, so that's definitely not a solution, since $f(\sqrt{1-y})=\sqrt{1-y}|\sqrt{1-y}|+1=2-y\neq y$. So, it happens that the only valid solution is $x=-\sqrt{1-y}$. When $x\geq 0$, similarly, you accurately find the inverse to be one of two values, but it happens to be $x=\sqrt{y-1}$, since it must be possible. In particular, just by refining the work you've already done a bit, we find that the inverse function is:
$$g(x)=\begin{cases}\sqrt{y-1} && \text{if }y\geq 1 \\ -\sqrt{1-y} && \text{if }y<1\end{cases}$$
which you could quickly check satisfies $f(g(x))=x$, if you wished.

Comment: Very well written. I have just one question if you don't mind. How did Wolfram Alpha$^{[1]}$ get the inverse to be $f^{-1}(x) = ±\sqrt{x-1}$?

$^{[1]}$ http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=inverse+of+x|x|%2B1

Comment: I don't know how it got it, but it's wrong. It's misleading since the plot of $f^{-1}$ it supplies looks correct - it's just not the plot of $\pm\sqrt{x-1}$ (which is imaginary for $x<1$ and multivalued elsewhere). I think it just plots $f$ exchanging coordinates $(x,f(x))\rightarrow (f(x),x)$ to make that graph - if you look at a page like [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=inverse+of+x%2B5sin%28x%29), it fails to find a closed form and the function isn't injective, but it plots the inverse anyways. I'm surprised to see it give a blatantly incorrect answer though...

Answer (score 2):

since the absolute value function is used one way, we can also make use of it in the other direction to give:
$$
f^{-1}(y) = \frac{y-1}{\sqrt{|y-1|}}
$$

Comment: Oh, that's good. Care to add how you got there? It's not too trivial for me, I'm very new to this.

Comment: forget  the constant $1$ and think of $y=f(x)=x|x|$. it is a parabola with the negative portion rotated through $\pi$ around the negative $X$-axis. obviously $x=f^{-1}(y)=sgn(y)\sqrt{|y|}$. now use $sgn(y)=\frac{y}{|y|}$. there is the exceptional point to be dealt with, but that is not the subject of this exercise, i think.

Answer (score 1):

If $a|a| = b|b|$. If $a=0$ or $b=0$ then $a=b=0$ and the function is injective.

Suppose that $a\neq0$ and $b\neq 0$ then $\frac{a}{b} = \frac{|b|}{|a|}$.

Let $x = \frac{a}{b}$, then the last equation reads: $x = \frac{1}{|x|}$ or $x |x| = 1$.

If $x>0$ then $x^2=1$ or $x=1$.

If $x<0$ then $-x^2=1$ (impossible). So the only possibility is $x=1$ or $\frac{a}{b}=1$ and then $a=b$

---